# C# Threading.Suspend in Obsolete, thread has been deprecated?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, monitoring, deadlock

In my application, I am performing my file reading by another thread(other than the GUI thread). There are two buttons that suspend and resume the Thread respectively.

```cs
private void BtnStopAutoUpd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    autoReadThread.Suspend();
}

private void BtnStartAutoUpd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    autoReadThread.Resume();
}
```

but I am facing this warning,

> Thread.Suspend has been deprecated.  Please use other classes in System.Threading, such as Monitor, Mutex, Event, and Semaphore, to synchronize Threads or protect resources.  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202

Anyhow, I run only a single thread (rather than a GUI thread), so How can I apply Synchronization here or monitor.

Update Code:

```cs
class ThreadClass 
{

    // This delegate enables asynchronous calls for setting the text property on a rich text box control.
    delegate void UpdateTextCallback(object text);

    // create thread that perform actual task
    public Thread autoReadThread = null;

    public ManualResetEvent _event = new ManualResetEvent(true);

    // a new reference to rich text box
    System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox Textbox = null;

    private volatile bool _run;

    public bool Run 
    {
        get 
        {
            return _run;
        }
        set 
        {
            _run = value;
        }
    }

    public ThreadClass(string name, System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox r1) 
    {
        Textbox = r1;
        Run = true;
        this.autoReadThread = new Thread(
            new ParameterizedThreadStart(UpdateText));
        
        this.autoReadThread.Start(name);
    }

    private void UpdateText(object fileName) 
    {
        //while (true)
        //{
        //    _event.WaitOne();
        //}
        while (Run) 
        {

            if (Textbox.InvokeRequired) 
            {
                UpdateTextCallback back = new UpdateTextCallback(UpdateText);
                
                Textbox.BeginInvoke(back, new object[] {
                        fileName
                     });
                     
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            } 
            else 
            {
                string fileToUpdate = (string) fileName;
                using(StreamReader readerStream = new StreamReader(fileToUpdate)) 
                {
                    Textbox.Text = readerStream.ReadToEnd();
                }
                
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

the run is bool value, a thread controls it(Initially it's true)

and to start a thread I am creating this class instance(this start thread also) in another class

Comment: You update does not show: a) How your thread is started, b) the complete thread method.

Comment: InvokeRequired is always true.  Your thread doesn't do anything useful, everything runs on the UI thread.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
 //true makes the thread start as "running", false makes it wait on _event.Set()
  ManualResetEvent _event = new ManualResetEvent(true); 
  Thread _thread = new Thread(ThreadFunc);

  public void ThreadFunc(object state)
  {
      while (true)
      {
          _event.Wait();

          //do operations here
      }
  }


  _thread.Start();

  // to suspend thread.
  _event.Reset();

  //to resume thread
  _event.Set();
```

Note that all operations are completed before the thread is "suspended"

**What you want**

```
private void ThreadFunc(object fileName)
{
    string fileToUpdate = (string)fileName;
    while (Run)
    {
        _event.WaitOne(); 

        string data;
        using (StreamReader readerStream = new StreamReader(fileToUpdate))
        {
            data = readerStream.ReadToEnd();
        }

        if (Textbox.InvokeRequired)
        {
            UpdateTextCallback back = new UpdateTextCallback(UpdateText);
            Textbox.BeginInvoke(back, new object[] { data });
        }

                Thread.Sleep(1000); 
    }       
}


private void UpdateText(string data)
{
    Textbox.Text = data;
}
```

Comment: Not working... execution stops at _event.Wait(); after that my operations are not getting executed.

Comment: Have you tried to use `_event.Set()`? I set the initial state to `false` on the `ManualResetEvent` which makes it wait on set before continuing

Comment: I didn't reached there. after_evenr.Wait() I wrote my code to get execute, but wait stmnt hangs there only. _event.reset and _evenr.Set I wrote in button events.

Comment: I'd personally make the first line `ManualResetEvent _event = new ManualResetEvent(true);`, since the default behaviour should be for the thread to run.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Correct. @Pawan Kumar: Changed to true in the `ManualResetEvent` constructor. Check the updated code.

Comment: @jgauffin & @Damien    ya then it is entring to my code but form get hangs. After the while(true) I am using one more while(true) [for running thread continuously ]

Comment: The code above works. We need to see more of your own code to tell you what the problem is. Update your question with your updated code. Both the code that uses the thread and the threadmethod.

Comment: Updated my answer yet again with a small example on how to get suspend/resume and periodic updates.

Comment: @jgauffin... hmm that really works. I get my fault. I keep that in ma mind. thanx

Answer (score 6):

The reason Suspend and Resume are deprecated is because there are no guarantees at what point in the execution the thread will be suspended on. This is a bad thing. The issue is described [here](https://blogs.msmvps.com/peterritchie/2006/10/13/system-threading-thread-suspend-is-obsolete-thread-suspend-has-been-deprecated/) as well as a solution.

The solution should involved a WaitHandle (maybe AutoResetEvent or ManualResetEvent) which you can use to signal to your autoReadThread to stop/start.

Answer (score 5):

I would use the Monitor mechanism for achieving pausing and resuming threads. The Monitor.Wait will cause the thread to wait for the Monitor.Pulse.

```
private bool _pause = false;
private object _threadLock = new object();

private void RunThread()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (_pause)
        {
            lock (_threadLock)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(_threadLock);
            }
        }

        // Do work
    }
}

private void PauseThread()
{
    _pause = true;
}

private void ResumeThread()
{
    _pause = false;
    lock (_threadLock)
    {
        Monitor.Pulse(_threadLock);
    }
}
```