# how to stop running thread and resume the same thread beside create new thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have using concurrent_queue.h to have queue that receive element from different thread -

Every time some thread add element to the concurrent queue i call some method that create new thread to get element from the queue and handle it ( calling some method that do something with this item )

```
concurrency::concurrent_queue<Item> _queue;


void handleItem(Item item)
{
    // do something with item  
}

// method that call every time add something to the queue - can be 
// situation that the queue contain more then one item 
void handleQueueItem()
{
    Item item;
    while (_queue.try_pop(item))
    {
        std::thread t1(&handleItem, item);      

        t1.join();      // wait till finish before handle next item.        
    }
}
```

I want to make the thread t1 in other way that i will not need to create new thread evry time i have something in the queue

I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Why not just start a thread that runs `handleQueueItem()` instead and remove any mention of `std::thread` from the function?

Comment: You mean like a `Sleep()` function?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux becuase this will be same - same create thread evry time i add something to queue

Comment: @TimRandall no .. not sleep .. i mean suspend thread ( line .net / jave ) and resume

Comment: @Yanshof c++ does not support externally suspending threads and many APIs that do support it are deprecating such features in modern editions because it's often unsafe. Example : [java](http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/07/why-stop-suspend-resume-of-thread-are.html) and [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509067/c-sharp-threading-suspend-in-obsolete-thread-has-been-deprecated). If your design calls for a suspend function to work, it's probably unsafe and needs to be redesigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of spinning up a thread in `handleQueueItem`, you can make `handleQueueItem` run in its own thread and it will run continuously.  That would look like

```
void handleItem(Item item)
{
    // do something with item  
}

void handleQueueItem()
{
    Item item;
    while (_queue.try_pop(item))
    {  
        handleItem(item)
    }
}

std::thread runner([](){ handleQueueItem(); });
```

You can even add a flag to the loop so you can stop the thread by adding a `std::atomic<bool>` variable and checking it in the loop like

```
std::atomic<bool> run = true;
void handleQueueItem()
{
    Item item;
    while (run && _queue.try_pop(item))
    {  
        handleItem(item)
    }
}

std::thread runner([](){ handleQueueItem(); });

// later on
run = false;
runner.join();
```

And then all you need to do is `run = false;` to have the loop stop.

Comment: Based on OP's latest comment, it seems he/she is worried that after the queue is empty, a new thread will need to spawned again. It seems the question is more fundamental, how to write a consumer worker consuming from an asynchronous job queue.

Comment: on this 'run' solution - you have busy waiting ? the thread will check the bool all the time

Comment: @Yanshof Note that `try_pop` *must* be synchronized or otherwise implemented in a race condition-free way.

Comment: @Yanshof Depends on how the queue is implemented, if `try_pop` blocks until it can pop then most of the time will be spent waiting on the queue.

Comment: @NathanOliver and is it possible to control it ? i don't understand - can you please exmplain

Comment: @Yanshof Possible to control what?

Comment: @Yanshof Did you implement whatever type `_queue` is? If so, then it's entirely in your control. If not, then you will have to look up how it works.

Comment: @NathanOliver the blocking queue until something will be add ( maybe i did not understand it right )

Comment: @Yanshof That is up t the implementation of `concurrency::concurrent_queue`.  I don't know what that is so I can't tell you if it blocks or not.  If it doesn't then this isn't the solution for you.

Comment: @NathanOliver  using #include <concurrent_queue.h>

Comment: @Yanshof From what library?

Comment: standard library

Comment: im using windows -

Comment: @Yanshof There is no `concurrent_queue` in the standard library.  If you are using [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/concrt/reference/concurrent-queue-class?view=vs-2017#try_pop) then the solution will not work.