# How to pause a specific thread in WinForms C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, winforms

I am creating an Windows Forms application by Visual Studio 2019, programming language is C#. I have a `DataGridView` containing information of many users. Each user is one row. When I start the app, each user will run in separate thread to do some actions (call API, show data to DataGridView, etc).

At the end of each row. I have a button called *PAUSE*, and another button called *RESTART*. When click *PAUSE* button, I expect the thread which is assigned to user in this row will be paused, and when click button *RESTART* the thread should be continued.

My problem is I don't know how to get the identifier of the thread which is assigned to a specific user. I tried add a name to the thread each time I create a new thread. But the Property name doesn't appear in the list of all running thread.

Create new thread for each user

```cs
foreach (User user in Users)
{
 Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
       // do some thing here: call API, etc. There are many activities here so I use multiple threads to optimize the performance.
    });                
 thread.IsBackground = true;
 thread.Name = User.Id; // this always return thread.Name with empty value ("") although the userId is not empty.
 thread.Start();                   
}
```

Get the list of all running threads of my app

```cs
System.Diagnostics.Process procces = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessThreadCollection threadCollection = procces.Threads;

foreach (System.Diagnostics.ProcessThread proccessThread in threadCollection)
{
  // I gues we can find the thread here, but I don't see any property Name
}
```

Comment: Why use threads at all? Why not tasks? Instead of one thread per "user", why not have a *few* threads processing user data as it appears? Besides, you can't modify the UI from a background thread. By using one thread per "user" you risk causing deadlocks as multiple threads try to modify the UI

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? One thread per "user" is how you think this can be solved, not the actual problem.

Comment: Thank you Panagiotis Kanavos. I think using one thread per user is the same with using threads to process user data because I have a lot of data to do. My actual problem is that: when I click the PAUSE/START button of a user, I don't know how to find the thread which I created for that user. Also I only have about 5 - 10 user, it's not so big I think

Comment: You keep describing the solution, not the problem. You wouldn't need to "pause" if you used a single method and async/await to process user data whenever needed. Or even run 10 tasks concurrently every 10 seconds in response to a timer. In any case, you can't "pause" a thread through the Thread. object. You can have it check and block on a synchronization primitive like an AutoResetEvent or ManualResetEvent. Instead of having 10 blocked threads though, it would be better to use tasks and have the runtime use as many threads as needed to handle the actual load without blocking

Comment: Thank you Panagiotis Kanavos. It's new. I will try your solution. You're very nice.

Comment: What is the `User.Id`? Is it a `static` property of the class `User`?

Comment: Yes it is static for each user

Comment: The [`static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) modifier declares a static member, which belongs to the type itself rather than to a specific object. So if the `Id` is `static`, it's one shared id for all users.

Comment: "it is static for each user" should be written as "it is static for all users", but that doesn't sound right either.

Answer (score 1):

A thread isn't really any different to a string name then; it's just another thing associated with a user?

```
class User{
    ...
    public Thread T{get; set;}
}
```

```
foreach (User user in Users)
{
    user.T = new Thread(() => ...
```

And knowing the user, you can get their thread.. I presume you keep ahold of the user somehow - you don't need some "go looking in the big collection of threads in my app to try find on that relates to a user based on some string that coincides with the user id" process; instead just "don't let go of the thread" :)

Comment: Thank you Caius. But I'm a bit confused. If don't assign anything to thread (such as user Id), then how can I find the correct thread when I click button PAUSE/START. Could you please clarify more details?

Comment: If you don't assign anything to thread (i.e. you don't make a new Thread and assign it to `user.T`,) then it won't be in the collection of threads!

Comment: You wouldn't be having this confusion if your boss came and said "I know the app can't do it right now, but I want it so every user should have the capability of storing a Social Security Number" - you'd just open up the user class and add `public string Ssn { get; set; }` - why is a thread any different?

Comment: The row in the datagridview represents a User, right? So the person clicking stuff in the app clicks PAUSE on the "john smith" row.. and from that you get the User (you get the button that was clicked, get the row its on, get the user the row is bound to, that's the object in memory representing John Smith), and that user has a T property that is john smith's thread.. You aren't looking through the "list of 100 threads in the app, finding one that has a name John  Smith", you're starting from the user that you still have ahold of and finding the thread you created and assigned to them

Comment: Thank you Caius. I understood you idea. It's very nice. I will try.

Comment: Caius Jard, thanks to your solution now I can find the thread. But I can't suspend the thread when click button PAUSE and resume it when click button RESTART. Methods Thread.Suspend() and Thread.Resume() has been deprecated. Would you please advise a better solution to pause/restart a Thread.

Comment: Er, just because they're been deprecated doesn't mean you can't use them, it just means that Microsoft have decided to take the methods away in some future version of the framework so you're getting some advance warning of it. None of this (using threads) is the way I'd go, but I don't know anything about the design requirements of your app or why you need a thread per user or what they do and whether threading is even necessary. All that is probably well beyond the scope of this question, maybe even any question (too broad) but ask one anyway. Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509067

Comment: Caius Jard thank you. My app has 6 users. I would create 6 threads for, each user one thread.  Each user do the same things: 1) Call api to get their data from serve. 2) Access a website and login account of each user. 3) After login will do something on that website: filling some form, submit something, etc... I have used ChromeDriver. So If I don't use thread, I have to wait the first user to finish all their works, then wait for the second user. Hope this is clear

Comment: I found a way to handle problem and it's works. Thank you so much. Just check the status of user before doing something.

Comment: @ vanminhquangtri. I am glad to hear that your problem is solved . Could you post your solution to this problem? And after you post your answer, you can click ‘✔’ to accept it as an answer. It is helpful for community members to solve the similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a dictionary.

Try this:

```
Dictionary<string, Thread> threads =
    Users
        .ToDictionary(u => u.Id, u => new Thread(() =>
        {
            // do some thing here
        }));

foreach (User user in Users)
{
    Thread thread = threads[user.Id];
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();
}
```

NB: Threads are expensive. Each thread has a 1MB stack. It you have a lot of users that's a lot of memory and overhead. A solution that reuses threads (perhaps using the thread pool) might be better.

Comment: Thank you Enigmativity. I will try you solution right now.